# Decimal to Binary conversion code works fine on online compilers but gives wrong answer on VS code. Why?

Tags: c++, binary

*Checked similar questions but no one answers my problem.*

This code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n = 6;
    int bit = 0, answer = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (n != 0) {

        bit = (n & 1);
        answer = answer + (pow(10, i) * bit);
        n = n >> 1;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Binary equivalent is : " << answer;

    return 0;
}
```

this code works fine on Online compiler and gives expected result which is 110 but on VS code it is returning wrong answer without any visible error. What am i missing here?

Attaching the VS code and online gdb compiler result here :
[VS Code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MDch.png)

[Online Gdb code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdRd6.png)

Comment: `pow` is not for integers.

Comment: anyhow its a waste of cpu cycles to calculate `pow(10,i)` in each iteration, when you can start with `accu = 10;` and `accu *= 10;` in every iteration

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i get your point but that still doesn't answers the question.

Comment: rounding errors on the result of `pow` can explain different results

Comment: the assumption that `pow(10,i) == 1000......0;` is generally wrong

Comment: vs code is not a compiler, and neither is gdb

Comment: This is exactly why any code that calls `pow` with two integer arguments is automatically broken, by definition. This is not what `pow` is for.

Comment: @LearningNoob123 *but that still doesn't answers the question.* -- Yes it does.  If you had done what was suggested, you wouldn't have the issue you're seeing now.

Comment: Detail: you're not converting decimal to binary, you're "converting" a number into a different number. Specifically, you're "converting" six into one hundred and ten (when it's succssful) and one hundred and nine (when it fails).